# Google image search by image

Tags: image, search

I've looked around, this question has been asked before but i would like to know if it was possible to do so, maybe without using an API, or using another  search-engine.

I would like to check the web for images, by searching with an image.

Is there any way to do so, if so can anybody point me in the right direction, i just can't seem to get started.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this currently with Google.  Drag and drop the image into the search field.

Just go to:

```
http://images.google.com
```

and drop your image over the search field.

Google used to have some images below the search field that you could drag and drop, as examples.